# EF Add filter to navigation property DbSet

Tags: entity-framework-6

I want to add .Where(e => e.PartitionId = x) to all entities in Linq to Entity expression.
User could send complex query which translates into multiple navigation property, for example
Order and its customers and customer's address.
I tried capturing DbSet access but it appears to only happen for Order entity and does not happen for any of navigation property.

I can't hard code query in my code because user could be asking for Order and get its navigation property or start from any of my 20 entities.

Answer (score 0):

I found  [EntityFramework.DynamicFilter](https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters) and it is working well so far